# Where is ObjectiveGit documentation

Tags: libgit2, objective-git

I am wondering where is ObjectiveGit Documentation. I checked the project on github (https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git) but couldn't find it there. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I use the test fixtures in `objective-git`, `libgit2`, and  `libgit2sharp` as my *documentation* sources, while the entire family of `libgit2` wrappers are amazing (including the libgit2 core lib), SDK-style docs are very limited, thus I refer to the unit test code as their code coverage is very complete... Of course, being open source, doc contributors are always welcome... ;-)

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, that is an excellent tip. Yet, I still would like to have an official documentation or anything that is close to it.